# Dropdown still showing when tapping back button on touch devices - safari ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, safari, touch

I have a menu that expands when the user click on a tab to show menu-dropdown for the respective tab. I'm using the code bellow in order to close menu-dropdown showing when tapping outside the menu area.

```
$(function() {
    $('*').click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.id != 'menu'){
            $('#menu .menu-dropdown').css( "display", "none" );
            $('#menu .menu-dropdown').removeAttr( 'style' );
        }
    });
});
```

I have a problem in iPad safari and it probably happens in other touch devices. The problem is that when I want to come back to the page after tapping on one of the menu-dropdown items the menu-dropdown is still expanded.

Is there anyway to close menu-dropdown so it is not there if the user taps the back button.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aauE2/) shows how it works, for some reason it works on jsfiddle.net but not on my server.

Comment: Why not simply close the menu regardless of where the user clicks?

Comment: I have been trying to do it but when I return to the page the dropdown menu is still open.